# использование Lambda

Tags: java

у меня есть программа которая принимает csv файл (там примерно тысяча) строк файл в таком формате 1;Адыгейск;Адыгея;Южный;12248;1973
добавляет это в список, а после нужно перевести в массив и найти количество городов в каждом регионе,

```
output должен быть такой:

Татарстан - 22
Вологодская область - 15
Хабаровский край - 7
Адыгея - 2
..................
```

Я это сделал в лоб, топорно, но регионов много и получается очень громоздко и не круто, я понимаю, что это можно реализовать с помощью лямбда выражений, возможно
что-то типа:

```
filter(cityList -> cityList.get(i).getRegion().equals("Татарстан")).count();
```

Но я не понимаю как это реализовать, так как еще совсем новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, и скажите, мой вариант это норма? или совсем плох, вот код:

```
public class ReaderClass {
    private void printFileContent(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
            List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] splitLine = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
                City city = new City(splitLine);
                cityList.add(city);

            }
            String[] arrayReg = new String[cityList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
                arrayReg[i] = cityList.get(i).getRegion();
            }
            int count1 = 0;
            int count2 = 0;
            int count3 = 0;
            int count4 = 0;
            int count5 = 0;
            int count6 = 0;
            int count7 = 0;
            int count8 = 0;
            int count9 = 0;

            String reg1 = "Татарстан";
            String reg2 = "Вологодская область";
            String reg3 = "Хабаровский край";
            String reg4 = "Адыгея";
            String reg5 = "Алтай";
            String reg6 = "Алтайский край";
            String reg7 = "Амурская область";
            String reg8 = "Архангельская область";
            String reg9 = "Башкортостан";
            String reg10 = "Белгородская область";
            String reg11 = "Брянская область";

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg1)) {
                    count1++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg1 + " - " + count1);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg2)) {
                    count2++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg2 + " - " + count2);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg3)) {
                    count3++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg3 + " - " + count3);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg4)) {
                    count4++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg4 + " - " + count4);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg5)) {
                    count5++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg5 + " - " + count5);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg6)) {
                    count6++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg6 + " - " + count6);


            for (int i = 0; i < arrayReg.length; i++) {
                if (arrayReg[i].equals(reg7)) {
                    count7++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(reg7 + " - " + count7);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("problems with the file" + e);
        }
        is.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReaderClass read = new ReaderClass();
        InputStream is = read.getFileAsIOStream("Файл.csv");
        read.printFileContent(is);
    }

    private InputStream getFileAsIOStream(final String fileName) {
        InputStream ioStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        if (ioStream == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName + " is not found");
        }
        return ioStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону словарей, например, `HashMap`

Comment: Как минимум можно список регионов собрать в список, по этому списку идти циклом и считать, сколько какой регион встретился - это сразу уменьшит дублирование кода. Дальше можно вообще не хранить предопределенный список регионов, просто идти по arrayReg, каждый новый регион добавлять в HashMap со значением 0, при повторном появлении увеличивать значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует использовать средства "нового" ввода/вывода для чтения файлов и Stream API для более лаконичного решения данной задачи, в которой можно выделить следующие подзадачи:

- получить поток строк из входного файла CSV-формата с разделителем `;`: `Files::lines` или `BufferedReader::lines`
- каждую строку разбить на колонки и преобразовать в экземпляр класса `City`: `Stream::map`
- построить мапу городов по регионам, используя коллекторы `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.mapping` + `Collectors.toSet`
- для полученной мапы отсортировать её содержимое по убыванию количества городов

Вариант реализации:

```java
public static void printRegionStats(String csvFile) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(csvFile))) {
        input
            .map(line -> line.split(";")) // Stream<String[]>
            .map(City::new) // Stream<City>, есть конструктор City(String...args)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                City::getRegion, // ключ - название региона
                Collectors.mapping(City::getCity, Collectors.toSet()) // множество уникальных городов
            )) // Map<String, Set<String>>
            .entrySet()
            .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>>
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                e -> e.getValue().size(), Comparator.reverseOrder()
            ))
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue().size()));
    }
}
```

Если во входном файле для каждого города гарантированно нет дубликатов, код можно упростить и сразу подсчитывать количество городов:

```java
public static void printRegionStats(String csvFile) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(csvFile))) {
        input
            .map(line -> line.split(";")) // Stream<String[]>
            .map(City::new) // Stream<City>, есть конструктор City(String...args)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                City::getRegion, // ключ - название региона
                Collectors.summingInt(c -> 1) // подсчет городов
            )) // Map<String, Integer>
            .entrySet()
            .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()));
    }
}
```

---

Для получения потока строк из сканера можно использовать метод:

```java
static Stream<String> streamScanner(Scanner scanner) {
    Spliterator<String> splt = Spliterators.spliterator(scanner, Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL);
    return StreamSupport.stream(splt, false)
            .onClose(scanner::close);
}
```

Соответственно, код может быть изменен так (добавил сортировку ключей регионов по алфавиту при совпадении значений):

```java
public static void printRegionStats(String csvFile) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> input = streamScanner(new Scanner(new File(csvFile)).useDelimiter("\\R"))) {
        input
            .map(line -> line.split(";")) // Stream<String[]>
            .map(City::new) // Stream<City>, есть конструктор City(String...args)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                City::getRegion, // ключ - название региона
                Collectors.summingInt(c -> 1) // подсчет городов
            )) // Map<String, Integer>
            .entrySet()
            .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
                .reversed()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            )
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Тестирование данного способа упрощается до следующего:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    printRegionStats("data.csv");
}
```

Вывод (тестовый вариант):

```
Татарстан - 2
Адыгея - 2
Алтайский край - 1
Красноярский край - 1
```

Comment: Просто в этой задаче одно из условий - это получение данных с помощью класса Scanner

Comment: Это не проблема, из сканера тоже можно получить поток строк, смотрите апдейт

Comment: @Алексей, перепроверил  и обновил ответ -- по крайней мере, сортировка здесь реализована, как и чтение данных из сканера.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы просто машины)) сколько лет понадобилось, чтобы так соображать

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы делаете, называется программирование путем исключения. И это антипаттерн. Вам постоянно нужно менять код, когда меняется количество регионов и чем больше регионов, тем длинее код (и он само собой дублирующийся). Это самый плохой подход из существующих.

Пробуйте так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReaderClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReaderClass read = new ReaderClass();
        List<City> cities = parseCsv(read.getFileAsIOStream("Файл.csv"));
        Map<String, Long> result = cities.stream().map(City::getRegion)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));        
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private InputStream getFileAsIOStream(final String fileName) {
        InputStream ioStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        if (ioStream == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName + " is not found");
        }
        return ioStream;
    }
    
    private static List<City> parseCsv(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
            List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] splitLine = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
                City city = new City(splitLine);
                cities.add(city);
            }
            return cities;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Отсутствует сортировка и корректный вывод результатов; операции `map(City::getRegion) + groupingBy(Function.identity())` заменяются `groupingBy(City::getRegion)`

Comment: @Nowhere Man про сортировку в задаче ничего не сказано, в каком формате нужно это выводить тоже, операции можно заменить, возможно, от этого стрим даже будет немного быстрее работать, но это не точно)

Comment: каким образом тогда можно переопределить toString, если  вывод нужен в определенном виде?

Comment: @Алексей toString вы не переопределите, поскольку вы имеете дело с коллекцией из коробки, но можно перебирать данную коллекцию и поэлементно выводить в консоль так, как вам этого хочется. если непонятно как это сделать, дайте пример желаемого вывода в консоль

Comment: @Дмитрий, цитата: `output должен быть такой  Татарстан - 22\nВологодская область - 15...`

Comment: в самом вверху в основном вопросе есть нужный формат вывода

Comment: @Алексей можно, к примеру, так : result.forEach((region, numb)->System.out.println(region + " - " + numb));